# javaFX event when objects are rendered

Tags: java, event-handling, javafx, javafx-8

I'd like to get noticed by an event when all the objects in the Scene/Stage are displayed. This sounds like JavaFX doesn't provide this feature. Am I Right ?

I explain why:

I have to update other objects of the scene based on a TableView scroll position. Hence, I'm looking up the VirtualScrollBar of the TableView by using:

```
tableView.lookupAll(".scroll-bar")
```

which returns the desired ScrollBar only after TableView is actually rendered. Null in "initialize" block.

Architecture:
I'm using a common frame - I'd say - containing an empty Pane updated runtime with actual content given the page I'd like to show.
Hence I know when the content is updated, but most of the time before the TableView is rendered, which prevents me to get the ScrollBar reference.

The TableView is part of a "page" and is added to the content Pane, no update on the stage itself.

I'm using Oracle JDK8.

Do you have any clue where I can sort this out ?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If all you want is the scroll position, wouldn't the `onScroll*` properties from `Node` do? E.g. [`onScrollFinished`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#onScrollFinishedProperty)

Comment: You're right, I only want the scroll position, but resulting from any kind of user actions. onScrollFinished is only binded to mouse wheel event, unfortunately not if the user clicks on the scroll buttons

Comment: I currently found a workaround : add a callback to the items observable list of the table itself which is always after TableView rendering and an instance variable to avoid duplicating calls.

Comment: What happens if you lookup the scrollbar in Platform.runLater() in initialize method?

Comment: nothing but null. Remember initialize is already in the FX thread...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get an answer:

The only workaround I found now is to add a callback to the items observable list of the table itself which is always after TableView rendering and an instance variable to avoid duplicates:

```
table.getItems().addListener(new ListChangeListener<T>() {

        @Override
        public void onChanged(Change<? extends T> c) {
            if (tableScrollBar == null){
                tableScrollBar = lookupScrollBar(); 
                tableScrollBar.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> arg0, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                        // do my job
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the `setOnShown()` method of the `Stage` class to be notified when the `Stage` is visible.   Once it is visible, all the controls have been created. The docs say as follows:

```
public final void setOnShown(EventHandler<WindowEvent> value)
```

> Sets the value of the property onShown.
>
> Property description:
>   Called just after the Window is shown.

Comment: Thanks, but already thought about it. This event is not triggered when the user changes the page as only the content Pane is updated. I don't want to hide/show the stage each time and reduce, for my point of view, the navigation experience. I updated my description accordingly.

Comment: And, I should have wrote it, every page has its own Controller, hence listening to Stage event might be confusing.

Answer (score 4):

This is no such event available.
However, you can override `layoutChildren()` and trigger all the listeners.

```
private boolean isRendered = false;
protected void layoutChildren() {
    super.layoutChildren();
    if(!isRendered){
        //This is the first time the node is rendered. Event trigger logic should be here
    }
    isRendered = true;
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution so far, overriding SkinBase gives total control over flow events without any intereference

Comment: I have used BooleanProperty for execution of the logic in the listener. This was as easy as pie, thanks a lot man.

Comment: In my case (JavaFX 17), layoutChildren() is also called in cases where nodes are not rendered. For example, nodes in a Tab that is not selected, or nodes in a ScrollPane outside its viewport. Thus, this seems not to be a general solution.